# Geting no page found error in Ajax request asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Contact/PopBid

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PopBid(int jobid)
    {

        var getjob = _context.jobService.GetById(jobid);
        return View();
    }
```

JavaScript

```
      function Singin(jobid) {
            $.fancybox({

                'transitionIn': 'elastic',
                'transitionOut': 'elastic',
                'easingIn': 'easeOutBack',
                'easingOut': 'easeInBack',
                'width': 850,
                'height': 394,
                href: "/Contact/PopBid",
                data: "jobid=" + jobid,
                'type': 'iframe'
            });
        }s

 <img alt="" onclick="javascript:Singin(@job.ID);" src="/Content/WalkFish/Images/bidimg1.png" style="width: 180px; height: 140px;">
```

onclick event

pop open well but get error in the pop that

Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Contact/PopBid

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are GETing /Contact/PopBid not POSTing to it.
Because of the `[HttpPost]` attribute above you method the GET action is not available.

Change the attribute to `[HttpGet]`

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult PopBid(int jobid)
{

    var getjob = _context.jobService.GetById(jobid);
    return View();
}
```

Comment: after making it [HttpGet]getting this error  The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'jobid' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult PopBid(Int32)' in 'WMF.Controllers.ContactController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: Try `data: { jobid: jobid }`, Check the URL that's build using the network tracer in you browser or somthing like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Comment: AliRıza Adıyahşi  no it is not null